# MaterialApp ThemeData iconTheme

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

I have some ListTile widgets around my app, and all of them have an icon.

From [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17799) I see that I need to override my ListTile with

```dart
ListTileTheme(
  iconColor: Colors.blue,
  child: ..
)
```

since the `ListTile.iconColor` is gray by default and doesn't fallback to `ThemeData.iconTheme.iconColor`.

I wonder if there is a way to specify the list tile theme in ThemeData, so I don't have to create a new widget just for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, there isn't, but this feature may arrive in the next flutter release: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31247